# How to subscribe to an Observable that is to be returned, while still returning an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I've got an AuthHttpService which extends Http.  Whenever a request is made, I return the Observable, but I would also like to take some action inside of the HTTPService itself.  How can I go about doing that?

for example:

```
  get(url: string) {
    this.pendingRequests++;
    return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '' + url, { headers: this.getHeaders(this.config.apiUrl + url) })
      .subscribe(() => {
        if (this.pendingRequests > 0) {
          this.pendingRequests--;
        }
      });

  }
```

I'm using `this.pendingRequests > 0` to show a loading spinner. I want to pass back the actual response to whichever service called authHttp.get(), but I want authHttp to manage `pendingRequests` all by itself, so how can I do something with it without subscribing ?  My services that call this method are complaining that `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Subscription'`, which makes sense, but I don't know how else to do this.

The error comes from when a component's service is calling AuthHttp.get, expecting an Observable, but instead getting a subscription.  I'm wondering if there's any way for AuthHttp to subscribe but still return the subscription

Comment: Why not `let myCall = this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '' + url, { headers: this.getHeaders(this.config.apiUrl + url) })` and then subscribe to `myCall` and then do the map and return it?

Comment: Did you try `switchMap`? With `switchMap` you can switch from an observable to another one and the subscriber won't need to do anything. You can see more here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: @silentsod That actually worked just fine..

Comment: Hey @vinagreti I've never used switchMap before.  How would that apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to apply a "side-effect" is through a `do` block

```
  get(url: string) {
    this.pendingRequests++;
    return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '' + url, { headers: this.getHeaders(this.config.apiUrl + url) })
      .do(() => {
        this.pendingRequests = Math.max(0, this.pendingRequest - 1);
      });
  }
```

Optionally you could get more advanced and use a `Subscription` to wrap each request:

```
const PendingRequest = (onStart, onFinish) => {
  onStart();
  return onFinish;
}

const defaultRequest = () => PendingRequest(
  () => this.pendingRequest++,
  () => this.pendingRequests = Math.min(0, this.pendingRequests - 1)
);

get(url: string) {
  return Observable.using(
    defaultRequest,
    pendingRequest => this.http.get(url, {headers})
  );
}
```

While the second one may appear a little more verbose it has the advantage of actually only updating the pending requests counter once the request *starts* i.e. when it is subscribed to (in the first iteration it is incremented on function call which is not the same as subscription).

Additionally it allows you to house any additional logic (think timing or metrics) you want around that request object without resorting to side effect variables.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @silentsod's recommendation, I'm now creating the observable, subscribing to it, and then returning it after.

```
let req = this.http.put(
  this.config.apiUrl + '' + url, JSON.stringify(this.request),
  { headers: this.getHeaders(this.config.apiUrl + url + JSON.stringify(this.request)) }
)
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
      let res: Response = err;
      window.location.replace(this.config.membershipUrl +
        '/#/Home?ReturnURL=' + this.config.appUrl + '/#/authorize&appID=24B89F21-54ED-4073-94AA-BDC354668667');
      return Observable.of(res.json());
    } else if (err.status === 500) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
    }
  });
req.subscribe(() => {
  if (this.pendingRequests.getValue() > 0) {
    pending = this.pendingRequests.getValue();
    this.pendingRequests.next(pending - 1);
  }
});
return req;
```

Comment: Note this will make the call twice.

Comment: So I just noticed...Now I'm not sure what to do.  I forgot that subscribing calls twice.

Comment: @paulpdaniels any idea how I can accomplish the same goal without calling twice?